# How can I show/hide a button added to the title bar of an NSWindow?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, events, notifications

I have created a method in an `NSWindow` extension that allows me to add a button next to the text in the title bar. This is similar to the "down chevron" button that appears in the title bar of Pages and Numbers. When the button is clicked, an arbitrary code, expressed as a closure, is run.

While I have that part working fine, I would also like the button to be invisible most of the time and only become visible when the mouse is scrolled into the title bar area. This would be mimicking the way that Pages and Numbers displays the button.

However, I'm having difficulties getting the show/hide to work properly. I believe I can do it if I make it completely custom in the application delegate, and possibly by subclassing `NSWindow`, but I would really like to keep it as a single method in an `NSWindow` extension. In this way the code would be easily reusable in multiple applications.

To accomplish this I believe I need to inject an additional handler/listener that will tell me when the mouse enters and leaves the appropriate area. I can define the necessary area using an `NSTrackingArea`, but I haven't figured out how to "inject" an event listener without the need of subclasses. Does anyone know how (or if) such a thing is possible?

Comment: Which button in Pages do you mean? Is `NSTrackingArea` what you're looking for?

Comment: The button is the "down chevron" button that appears next to the document name in the title bar when the mouse is over that area. Pressing it allows you to move the document to another location. I'm trying to mimic that behaviour, although in my case the sheet that comes down does not have you moving a document, but changing the port that my app is monitoring. I've tried `NSTrackingArea`, but so far haven't managed to get it to solve the problem. Right now I'm thinking I would have to subclass `NSWindow` which would not be the end of the world, but is also not ideal.

Comment: How about hiding the image instead of the button?

Comment: I now have a solution to the problem. It uses an `NSTrackingArea` as suggested by @Willeke, but what I had to do was to add an additional object to the menu bar. Specifically I added an invisible view from a custom class that setup the tracking area and the `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` methods. That tracking area - which covers the entire title bar - then enables/disables the button of interest.

Comment: I will now cleanup my code and, if the moderators reopen this issue, I will post the complete answer. Essentially I should now have an `NSWindow` extension that adds a method `addTitleActionButton` that puts everything in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to handling the show/hide based on the mouse position was to use an `NSTrackingArea` to signify the portion that we are interested in, and to handle the mouse enter and mouse exit events. But since this can't be done directly on the title bar view (since we have to subclass the view in order to add the event handlers) we need to create an additional NSView that is invisible but covers the area we want to track.

I'll post the full code below, but the key parts related to this question are the `TrackingHelper` class defined near the bottom of the file and the way it is added to the `titleBarView` with its constrains set to be equal to the size of the title bar. The class itself is designed to take three closures, one for the mouse enter event, one for the mouse exit, and one for the action to take when the button is pressed. (Technically the latter doesn't really need to be part of the `TrackingHelper`, but it is a convenient place to put it to ensure it does not go out of scope while the UI still exists. A more correct solution would be to subclass `NSButton` to keep the closure, but I have always found subclassing `NSButton` to be a royal pain.)

Here is the full text of the solution. Note that this has a couple of things that depend on another library of mine - but they are not necessary for the understanding of this problem and are used to deal with the button image. If you wish to use this code you will need to replace the `getImage` function with one that creates the image you want. (And if you want to see what `KSSCocoa` is adding, you can obtain it from https://github.com/klassen-software-solutions/KSSCore)

```
//
//  NSWindowExtension.swift
//
//  Created by Steven W. Klassen on 2020-02-24.
//

import os
import Cocoa
import KSSCocoa

public extension NSWindow {
    /**
     Add an action button to the title bar. This will add a "down chevron" icon, similar to the one used in
     Numbers and Pages, just to the right of the title in the title bar. When clicked it will run the given
     lambda.
     */
    @available(OSX 10.14, *)
    func addTitleActionButton(_ lambda: @escaping () -> Void) -> NSButton {
        guard let titleBarView = getTitleBarView() else {
            fatalError("You can only add a title action to an app that has a title bar")
        }
        guard let titleTextField = getTextFieldChild(of: titleBarView) else {
            fatalError("You can only add a title action to an app that has a title field")
        }

        let trackingHelper = TrackingHelper()
        let actionButton = NSButton(image: getImage(),
                                    target: trackingHelper,
                                    action: #selector(trackingHelper.action))
        actionButton.setButtonType(.momentaryPushIn)
        actionButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        actionButton.isBordered = false
        actionButton.isEnabled = false
        actionButton.alphaValue = 0

        trackingHelper.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        trackingHelper.onButtonAction = lambda
        trackingHelper.onMouseEntered = {
            actionButton.isEnabled = true
            actionButton.alphaValue = 1
        }
        trackingHelper.onMouseExited = {
            actionButton.isEnabled = false
            actionButton.alphaValue = 0
        }
        titleBarView.addSubview(trackingHelper)
        titleBarView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[trackingHelper]-0-|",
                                                                   options: [], metrics: nil,
                                                                   views: ["trackingHelper": trackingHelper]))
        titleBarView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[trackingHelper]-0-|",
                                                                   options: [], metrics: nil,
                                                                   views: ["trackingHelper": trackingHelper]))

        titleBarView.addSubview(actionButton)
        titleBarView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[titleTextField]-[actionButton(==7)]",
                                                                   options: [], metrics: nil,
                                                                   views: ["actionButton": actionButton,
                                                                           "titleTextField": titleTextField]))
        titleBarView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-1-[actionButton]-3-|",
                                                                   options: [], metrics: nil,
                                                                   views: ["actionButton": actionButton]))

        DistributedNotificationCenter.default().addObserver(
            actionButton,
            selector: #selector(actionButton.onThemeChanged(notification:)),
            name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification"),
            object: nil
        )

        return actionButton
    }

    fileprivate func getTitleBarView() -> NSView? {
        return standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.superview
    }

    fileprivate func getTextFieldChild(of view: NSView) -> NSTextField? {
        for subview in view.subviews {
            if let textField = subview as? NSTextField {
                return textField
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}


fileprivate extension NSButton {
    @available(OSX 10.14, *)
    @objc func onThemeChanged(notification: NSNotification) {
        image = image?.inverted()
    }
}

@available(OSX 10.14, *)
fileprivate func getImage() -> NSImage {
    var image = NSImage(sfSymbolName: "chevron.down")!
    if NSApplication.shared.isDarkMode {
        image = image.inverted()
    }
    return image
}


fileprivate final class TrackingHelper : NSView {
    typealias Callback = ()->Void

    var onMouseEntered: Callback? = nil
    var onMouseExited: Callback? = nil
    var onButtonAction: Callback? = nil

    override func mouseEntered(with event: NSEvent) {
        onMouseEntered?()
    }

    override func mouseExited(with event: NSEvent) {
        onMouseExited?()
    }

    @objc func action() {
        onButtonAction?()
    }

    override func updateTrackingAreas() {
        super.updateTrackingAreas()
        for trackingArea in self.trackingAreas {
            self.removeTrackingArea(trackingArea)
        }

        let options: NSTrackingArea.Options = [.mouseEnteredAndExited, .activeAlways]
        let trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: self.bounds, options: options, owner: self, userInfo: nil)
        self.addTrackingArea(trackingArea)
    }
}
```